# Difference in Rounding between Android App and Javascript code

Tags: javascript, android, rounding, rounding-error

I get two different results when attempting to calculate and round these numbers. The **today** number is **336887** and the **yesterday** number is **336582**. I had a similar issue with another field, but after updating the Java code the discrepancy disappeared.

**Javascript Code:**

```
    document.getElementById("txt1").value = ((today - yesterday) / 10000).toFixed(3);
```

**Android Code:**

```
    public Double RoundDouble(Double num, Integer places)
    {
        Double temp = Math.pow(10.0, places);

        num = num * temp;
        Math.round(num);
        num = num / temp;

        return num;
    }

    Double total = RoundDouble((today - yesterday) / 10000,3);
    txt1.setText(df.format(total ));
```

The Javascript code returns **.031** while the Android code returns **.030**. I did the Math and before rounding, the number is **.0305**. I'm unsure what is causing this issue as the other field I had the issue with rounds **.0295** to **.030** properly.

Comment: different floating point representations on different hardware and operating systems will treat rounding a little different. with floating point values, sometimes there isnt a perfect representation of certain numbers.

Comment: I had another field that was a similar issue. It wasn't properly rounding .0295 to .030, but after I changed my rounding method in the Android App it appears to have fixed the issue for that specific field. I do not quite understand why it fixed the issue for one field, but not the other.

Comment: "document.getElementById" isn't ASP code.  Looks like client side code.

Comment: Thank you for pointing that out. Honest mistake on my part. Code is JavaScript, not ASP. Edited question to reflect this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The fraction  ((336887 - 336582) / 10000) is not representable as an IEEE-754 double precision number. If you try `((336887 - 336582) / 10000).toFixed(20)` you'll get 0.03049999999999999933.
The reason for the difference in the Android version could be the way you handle the return of `Math.round(num)`: you ignore it. You might find it more useful to change the line to `num = Math.round(num);`.
It is also possible to change the [rounding mode](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/math/RoundingMode.html) in Android. The default rounding mode in ECMAScript is nearest-to-even which is HALF_EVEN in Android.

Comment: Consolidating all of the code involved in the rounding to: `num = Math.round(num * temp) / temp;` fixed the issue. Thanks for the help! Feel free to update your answer with this code.